# Unable To Use "Delete" key in SSN Input Field

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am unable to use the "Delete" key to delete characters within this SSN Input field. If you enter nine numbers, then use the arrow keys to navigate to a portion of the string, and press the Delete button (not Backspace), the expected behavior does not happen. Is there a way to allow for the auto-formatting of the SSN (which is what the rest of the code does) while still allowing for the Delete button to behave as expected?

```js
// SSN validation
// trap keypress - only allow numbers
$('input.ssn').on('keypress', function(event) {
  // trap keypress
  var character = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (!isInteger(character)) {
    return false;
  }
});

// checks that an input string is an integer, with an optional +/- sign character
function isInteger(s) {
  if (s === '-') return true;
  var isInteger_re = /^\s*(\+|-)?\d+\s*$/;
  return String(s).search(isInteger_re) != -1
}

// format SSN 
$('input.ssn').on('keyup', function() {
  var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  var newVal = '';

  if ((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
    newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
    val = val.substr(3);
  }
  if (val.length > 5) {
    newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
    newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
    val = val.substr(5);
  }
  newVal += val;
  this.value = newVal;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="u22" class="ax_text_field">
  <input id="u22_input" class="ssn" type="text" value="" data-label="ssn1" maxlength="11" />
</div>
```

Comment: Cant reproduce, tested on Firefox: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x64. [DEL] & [BACKSPACE] both are working.

Comment: Also can't reproduce in Chrome on Mac

Comment: You would have this problem if you used a `keydown` handler instead of `keypress`, since it runs for all keys, not just character keys.

Comment: Okay,  interesting. My problem is definitely occurring on Chrome with Windows 10. The problem persists when changing to keypress. Any Windows people out there able to reproduce?